# Intermittent errors from Azure Storage Blob SAS URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have an application that displays links to files in Azure Storage. Since recently upgrading to .Net Framework 4.8 and switching to the newer Azure.Storage name spaces, the links being generated throw an error about a third of the time. I have set the StartsOn and EndsOn times to different ranges to account for server time drift but I still get the error.  (This was the solution for the closest previous question I could find.)

If there are multiple uris on the page, then there could be a mix of some working and some not working or all working or all not working.

Thanks in advance for any help.

The Error:

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId: XXXXXXXXXXXX Time:2023-02-28T16:09:05.8202280Z
> Signature fields not well formed

Details:
Webforms project
Framework 4.8
Packages used:
Azure Storage Blobs v12.15
Azure Storage Common v12.14
Azure Storage Shares v12.13

```
/// <summary>
/// Return list of URIs to download blobs in given folder.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="folderName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>

public List<StorageItem> GetBlobSasUris(string folderName)
{
    BlobContainerClient container = getContainer(folderName);
    var response = container.GetBlobs(BlobTraits.All);

    List<StorageItem> urlList = new List<StorageItem>();
    foreach (var blobItem in response)
    {
        BlobClient blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
        blobClient.GetProperties();
        StorageItem blobUri = getBlobUri(blobClient);
        urlList.Add(blobUri);
    }
    return urlList;
}

private BlobContainerClient getContainer(string folderName)
{
    var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(_storageConnectionString);
    var container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(folderName);
    container.CreateIfNotExists();
    return container;
}
_storageConnectionString=Connection string from Azure Storage Account

`private StorageItem getBlobUri(BlobClient blob)
{

    Uri uri = GetUserDelegationSasBlob(blob);
    //Return the URI string for the container, including the SAS token.
    StorageItem storageItem = new StorageItem();
    storageItem.FileName = blob.Name;
    storageItem.Uri = uri.ToString();// blobUriBuilder.ToUri().ToString();

    var properties = blob.GetProperties().Value;
    storageItem.Created = properties.CreatedOn.DateTime;

    storageItem.LastModified = properties.LastModified.DateTime;
    //var accessTier = properties.StandardBlobTier;
    var accessTier = properties.AccessTier;//Hot/Cool/Archive.
    storageItem.AccessTier = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessTier) ? 
        (AccessTier)Enum.Parse(typeof(AccessTier), accessTier) : AccessTier.Unknown;
    return storageItem;
}

private Uri GetUserDelegationSasBlob(BlobClient blobClient)
{

 BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient =
 blobClient.GetParentBlobContainerClient().GetParentBlobServiceClient();
 
 BlobContainerClient containerClient =         blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobClient.BlobContainerName);
 
 PageBlobClient pageBlobClient = containerClient.GetPageBlobClient(blobClient.Name);
 
   //Tested with different offset ranges up to -2 hours and +6
 All produce error with similar frequency.
 BlobSasBuilder blobSasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
     {
 BlobContainerName = containerClient.Name,
 StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-30),
 ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(3),
         //IPRange = new SasIPRange(IPAddress.None, IPAddress.None),
 Resource = "b",
 Protocol = SasProtocol.Https,
 
       };
 blobSasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);
 
     //These URIs fail occasionally.  Trying an older method below.
     //var sasUri = pageBlobClient.GenerateSasUri(blobSasBuilder);
     //return sasUri;
 
     //This generates URIs that fail with similar frequency as above.
 BlobUriBuilder su = new BlobUriBuilder(pageBlobClient.Uri)
     {
 Sas = blobSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(new 
          StorageSharedKeyCredential(GetKeyValueFromConnectionString("AccountName"), 
            GetKeyValueFromConnectionString("AccountKey")))
    };
    return su.ToUri();
}
```

Things I've tried:
Rotating the Azure Storage Access Key
Upgrading the Azure.Storage namespaces.
Adjusting the BlobSasBuilder StartsOn and ExpiresOn time window.
Changed method of generating SAS Uri from PageBlobClient.GenerateSasUrI to using BlobUriBuilding.ToUri() method.

Edit:
Here are samples of the links that were generated on the same page load: The first didn't work and the second did.

Does not work:
"https://[AccountName].blob.core.windows.net/Folder3417/testImage.png?sv=2021-12-02&spr=https&st=2023-02-28T18:29:22Z&se=2023-02-28T21:59:22Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=rzbq/5jLC8eGZF+1lbhaNDoJx92giC8rwldnWBLCwFc="

Works:
"https://[AccountName].blob.core.windows.net/Folder3417/53870582_2454669444545873_895079374989033472_o.jpg?sv=2021-12-02&spr=https&st=2023-02-28T18:29:22Z&se=2023-02-28T21:59:22Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=4xQMBFTWkwqb7I1ThUgHhvQ/xGH2m/GOCfRcfkotzLE="

Comment: Please share one of the failing SAS tokens. Also share the code where you are using the SAS URL.

Comment: I've added samples of links from the same page load.  First did not work the second did.

Comment: First link did not work because the `sig` value has a `+` sign in it which is getting escaped somehow when you use it. Please check the code where you are using the SAS URL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gurav Mantri’s comment, I found the solution.
In the method `getBlobUri`
I changed this line:

```
 storageItem.Uri = uri.ToString();
```

to this

```
storageItem.Uri =  uri.OriginalString;
```